# Using Meteor.ObjectID as a type in SimpleSchema

Tags: mongodb, meteor, simple-schema

I have two Schemas using SimpleSchema - say Schema1 and Schema2. I want to reference the internal ObjectId (_id) from Schema1 in Schema2. How do I go about doing this?

Schema1 looks like this:

```
Schema1 = new SimpleSchema({
    aitem: {
        type: String
    },
    anitem: {
        type: String
    }
});
```

Schema2 looks like this:

```
Schema2 = new SimpleSchema({
    aaitem: {
        type: String
    },
    aanitem: {
        type: String
    },
    refItem: {
        type: Mongo.ObjectID
    }
});
```

When I try an insert in Meteor it says cannot validate ObjectID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo.ObjectId is not an acceptable validator.  The internal _id values are strings to JavaScript, so you can do: `type: String` and that should work.

Comment: Maybe back in the day this didn't work, but on a project I looked into, running on meteor 1.8.1, validating with `Mongo.ObjectID` does work. As does the way of @BPiltz. Probably the OP's problem was something else.

Answer (score 1):

Use: `Mongo.Collection.ObjectID`